# Show user id in url after login

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm Using Express Js Framework And MongoDB Database And I Want to Show Username In URL After User Login Successful. This Is My Code For Login Now How Can I Render User With Username In URL ?

This is my code

```
router.post('/login',  function (req, res, next) {
  if (req.body.username && req.body.password)
  {
    User.authenticate(req.body.username, req.body.password, function (error, user)
    {
      if (error || !user)
      {
        var err = new Error('Wrong username or password.');
        err.status = 401;
        return res.redirect('/login');
      }
      else
      {
        req.session.userId = user._id;
        if(user.roles=='admin')
        {
        return res.redirect('/admin');
        }else if(user.roles=='teacher')
        {
          console.log('teacher login');
          return res.redirect('/teacher');
        }else
        {
          console.log('Time Table Creator login');
          return res.redirect('/creator');
        }

      }
    });
  }else
  {
    var err = new Error('All fields required.');
    err.status = 400;
    return next(err);
  }
});

router.get('/login',function(req,res){
  res.render('login', { });
});

//Login Logic ends

//Get page after login
router.get('/admin', mid, function(req, res) {

    res.render('admin_dashboard',{});

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your admin route to allow path param and then pass username like below. I have changed it for admin see below

```
 router.post('/login',  function (req, res, next) {
      if (req.body.username && req.body.password)
      {
        User.authenticate(req.body.username, req.body.password, function (error, user)
        {
          if (error || !user)
          {
            var err = new Error('Wrong username or password.');
            err.status = 401;
            return res.redirect('/login');
          }
          else
          {
            req.session.userId = user._id;
            if(user.roles=='admin')
            {
            return res.redirect(`/admin/${req.body.username}`);
            }else if(user.roles=='teacher')
            {
              console.log('teacher login');
              return res.redirect('/teacher');
            }else
            {
              console.log('Time Table Creator login');
              return res.redirect('/creator');
            }

          }
        });
      }else
      {
        var err = new Error('All fields required.');
        err.status = 400;
        return next(err);
      }
    });

    router.get('/login',function(req,res){
      res.render('login', { });
    });

    //Login Logic ends

    //Get page after login
    router.get('/admin/:id', mid, function(req, res) { // change your route like this

        res.render('admin_dashboard',{});


  });
```